# toString() With Recursion Java

Tags: java, string, recursion

I have this really weird issue with my program and the test class provided. The goal is to return a string in the exact format provided. However, when I run the test class, it tells me my string is wrong, even though it is exactly the same as the string in the test class. I am not sure why it is coming up as an incorrect string, even though the string is correct. Thanks!
This is the class:

```
public class RecursionLinkedList
{
private Node firstNode;
private int numberOfEntries;

public RecursionLinkedList()
{
        firstNode = null;
        numberOfEntries = 0;
}

public void add(int aData)
{
        if(numberOfEntries == 0)
        {
    firstNode = new Node(aData);
        }
        else
        {
            firstNode = new Node(aData, firstNode);
        }

    numberOfEntries++;
}

/**
 * boolean contains(int aData)
 * 
 * See whether this RecursionLinkedList contains aData
 * @param aData  a data to be located
 * @return true if this RecursionLinkedList contains aData,
 *         or false otherwise.
 */
public boolean contains(int aData)
{
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        if(currentNode == null) {
    return false;
        }

        if(currentNode.data == aData) {
    return true;
        }

        else {
    return contains1(aData, currentNode);
        }
}

/**
 * int getFrequencyOf(int aData)
 * 
 * Counts the number of times a given data appears in this
 * RecursionLinkedList.
 * 
 * @param aData  the data to be counted
 * @return the number of times aData appears in this RecursionLinkedList
 */
public int getFrequencyOf(int aData)
{
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        int frequency = 0;
        if(currentNode == null) {
    return frequency;
        }

        else {
            frequency = getFrequencyOf1(aData, currentNode);
    return frequency;
        }

}

/**
 * String toString()
 * 
 * Return a string representation of this RecursionLinkedList. For example,
 * if this RecursionLinkedList contains 1, 2, 3, 5, 2 and 3 from the first
 * index to the last index, the returned string should be
 * "[1,2,3,5,2,3]"
 * @return the string representation of this RecursionLinkedList.
 */
public String toString()
{
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        String str1 = "[";
        String str = toString1(currentNode);
        String str2 = "]";
        return str1 + str + str2;   
}

/**
 * int getIndexOf(int aData)
 * 
 * Return the index of the first aData where the first index of
 * the first item in this RecursionLinkedList is 0.
 * 
 * @param aData  the data to be located
 * @return the index of the first aData.
 */
public int getIndexOf(int aData)
{
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        int index = 0;
        if(currentNode == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        else {
            index = getIndexOf1(aData, currentNode);
            return index;
        }

}

    public boolean contains1(int aData, Node node)
    {
        Node currentNode = node;

        if(currentNode == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if(currentNode.data == aData) {
            return true;
        } 

        else {
            return contains1(aData, currentNode.next);
        }
 }

    public int getFrequencyOf1(int aData, Node node)
{
    Node currentNode = node;
            int frequency = 0;
    if(currentNode == null) {
                return frequency;
    }

    if(currentNode.data == aData) {
                frequency = 1 + getFrequencyOf1(aData, currentNode.next);
    }

    else {
                frequency = getFrequencyOf1(aData, currentNode.next);
    }
            return frequency;
}

    public String toString1(Node node)
{
    Node currentNode = node;

            if(currentNode == null) {
                return "\b";
            }

            else {
                int i = currentNode.data;
                String str = Integer.toString(i);
                String str1 = str + ","+toString1(currentNode.next);
                return str1;
            }

}

    public int getIndexOf1(int aData, Node node)
{
    Node currentNode = node;
    int index = 0;
    if(currentNode == null) {
                return 0;
    }

    if(currentNode.data == aData) {
                return index;
    }

    else {
                index = 1 + getIndexOf1(aData, currentNode.next);
                return index;
    }

}

private class Node
{
    private int data;
    private Node next;

    private Node(int aData, Node nextNode)
    {
        data = aData;
        next = nextNode;
    }

    private Node(int aData)
    {
        this(aData, null);
    }
}
}
```

And this is the test class:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class RecursionLLTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    RecursionLinkedList rll = new RecursionLinkedList();
    int point = 0;
    boolean isError = false;

    System.out.println("Create an empty RecursionLinkedList named rll.");

    System.out.print("Test the method contains() on an empty RecursionLinkedList: ");
    if(rll.contains(5) != false)
    {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
        System.out.println("Nothing is added into RecursionLinkedList rll.");
        System.out.println("rll.contains(5) should return 0.");
        System.out.println("But your rll.contains(5) returns " + rll.contains(5) + ".");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("PASS");
        point++;
    }

    System.out.print("Test the method getFrequencyOf() on an empty RecursionLinkedList: ");
    if(rll.getFrequencyOf(5) != 0)
    {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
        System.out.println("Nothing is added into RecursionLinkedList rll.");
        System.out.println("rll.getFrequencyOf(5) should return 0.");
        System.out.println("But your rll.getFrequencyOf(5) returns " + rll.getFrequencyOf(5) + ".");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("PASS");
        point++;
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = 20;
    int[] array = new int[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }

    System.out.println("Add the following integer into rll:");
    String s = "]";

    for(int i = 0; i < num  - 1; i++)
    {
        int temp = rand.nextInt(5);
        System.out.print(temp + " ");
        s = "," + temp + s;
        array[temp]++;
        rll.add(temp);
    }
    int temp = rand.nextInt(5);
    System.out.println(temp);
    s = "[" + temp + s;
    array[temp]++;
    rll.add(temp);


    System.out.println("\nTest the method contains() on a non-empty RecursionLinkedList");
    System.out.print("  - Test rll.contains(-1): ");
    if(rll.contains(-1) != false)
    {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
        System.out.println("No -1 has been added into the RecursionLinkedList rll.");
        System.out.println("rll.contains(-1) should return 0.");
        System.out.println("But your rll.contains(-1) returns " + rll.contains(-1));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("PASS");
        point++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("  - Test rll.contains(" + i + "): ");
        if(rll.contains(i) != (array[i] != 0))
        {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("There are " + array[i] + " in RecursiveLinkedList rll.");
            System.out.println("rll.contains(" + i + ") should return " + (array[i] != 0));
            System.out.println("But your rll.contains(" + i + ") returns " + rll.contains(i));
            isError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("PASS");
        }
    }

    if(!isError)
    {
        point++;
        isError = false;
    }

    System.out.print("  - Test rll.contains(5): ");
    if(rll.contains(5) != false)
    {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
        System.out.println("No 5 has been added into the RecursionLinkedList rll.");
        System.out.println("rll.contains(5) should return 0.");
        System.out.println("But your rll.contains(5) returns " + rll.contains(5));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("PASS");
        point++;
    }

    System.out.println("Test the method getFrequencyOf() on a non-empty RecursionLinkedList");
    System.out.print("  - Test rll.getFrequencyOf(-1): ");
    if(rll.getFrequencyOf(-1) != 0)
    {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
        System.out.println("No -1 has been added into the RecursionLinkedList rll.");
        System.out.println("rll.getFrequencyOf(-1) should return 0.");
        System.out.println("But your rll.getFrequencyOf(-1) returns " + rll.getFrequencyOf(-1));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("PASS");
        point++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("  - Test rll.getFrequencyOf(" + i + "): ");
        if(rll.getFrequencyOf(i) != array[i])
        {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println(i + " has been added to the RecursionLinkedList " + array[i] + " times.");
            System.out.println("rll.getFrequencyOf(" + i + ") should return " + array[i] + ".");
            System.out.println("But your rll.getFrequencyOf(" + i + ") returns " + rll.getFrequencyOf(i));
            isError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("PASS");
        }
    }

    if(!isError)
    {
        point++;
        isError = false;
    }

    System.out.print("  - Test rll.getFrequencyOf(5): ");
    if(rll.getFrequencyOf(5) != 0)
    {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
        System.out.println("No 5 has been added into the RecursionLinkedList rll.");
        System.out.println("rll.getFrequencyOf(5) should return 0.");
        System.out.println("But your rll.getFrequencyOf(5) returns " + rll.getFrequencyOf(5));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("PASS");
        point++;
    }

    System.out.print("Test the method toString(): ");
    if(!s.equals(rll.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
        System.out.println("rll.toString() should return the string \"" + s + "\".");
        System.out.println("But your rll.toString() returns the string \"" + rll.toString() + "\".");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("PASS");
        point++;
    }


    System.out.println("Test the method getIndexOf()");
    System.out.println("Currently the rll is " + rll + ".");

    String[] str = rll.toString().split(",");
    str[0] = str[0].substring(1);
    str[str.length - 1] = str[str.length - 1].substring(0, 1);

    for(int i = -1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Test the method getIndexOf(" + i + "): ");
        if(getIndex(str,i) != rll.getIndexOf(i))
        {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("The index of " + i + " should be " + getIndex(str,i) + ".");
            System.out.println("But your rll.getIndexOf(" + i + ") returns " + rll.getIndexOf(i) + ".");
            isError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("PASS");
        }
    }

    if(!isError)
    {
        point++;
        isError = false;
    }

    System.out.println("Your current point is " + point + ".");
}

public static int getIndex(String[] str, int s)
{
    int result = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        if(s == Integer.parseInt(str[i]))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is it failing? What String were you expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: I am expecting the String to be exactly the same as the String generated in the test class. The String is in the format [5,4,3,2,1]. My toString method is producing the exact same String, but the if statement if(!s.equals(rll.toString())) in the test class is coming up for some reason, even though this statement is not true at all.

Comment: Did you use a debugger or something to see what `s` value is and what `rl1.toString()` value is? If so, what are the two outputs?

Comment: I ran a debugger several times, and the output is the same. For example, I get [0,3,2,4,4,2,3,1,1,4,4,1,1,1,3,2,0,2,4,2] from the test class and [0,3,2,4,4,2,3,1,1,4,4,1,1,1,3,2,0,2,4,2] from my toString method.

Comment: They aren't in fact the same. I just used a debugger in Eclipse. Not only can I see that `rll.toString()` is not the same, but if you check the lengths of both of those, `s.length` is 41 and `rll.toString().length` is 43

Comment: Okay I see what happened thanks!

Comment: Np! Glad you got the answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `toString1(Node)` method.

```
    if (currentNode == null) {
        return "\b";
    }
```

The `\b` character is what you're seeing at the end in your test output.

> rll.toString() should return the string "[1,1,1,3,4,2,2,1,0,1,2,1,0,4,4,4,2,1,1,2]".
>
> But your rll.toString() returns the string "[1,1,1,3,4,2,2,1,0,1,2,1,0,4,4,4,2,1,1,2,?]".

With a slight adjustment to the method as follows, the test in question passes.

```
public String toString1(Node node)
{
    Node currentNode = node;
    if (currentNode == null) {
        return "\b";
    }
    int i = currentNode.data;
    String str = Integer.toString(i);
    if (currentNode.next != null) {
        str = str
            + "," + toString1(currentNode.next);
    } 
    return str;
}
```

Though I would recommend you change a few things here:

- Use a `StringBuilder` rather than all that thrashing on string concatenation.
- Replace recursion with a loop. If your list gets too big you're going to run out of stack space with that recursive method.
- I don't think you ever want to return that `\b` character, as it doesn't represent an integer and your `indexOf()` method seems to be choking on the concept as well.

Comment: @zackster1171: note that `\b` does *not* delete the last character in a string; it only does something special when printed.